# Starter quantity w/ Mr. Malty Calculator

Tags: yeast, high-gravity, pitching, pitching-rate

I have an imperial stout that seems to have slowed fermentation ~ 1.040. I made a 2L starter w/ Super San Diego yeast on stir plate and pitched it at high krausen.. no decanting.

Based on Mr. Malty's Yeast calculator, I needed 2.75L of starter for an OG 1.10. So I took slurry from my cider (Champagne yeast), created two 2L starters and cold crashing now and will decant this time and pitch both. The amount of yeast at bottom of the starters is very small, less than an inch in an Erlenmeyer flask. Then I got to thinking, is Mr. Malty's calculation of 2.75L of starter including all the liquid or strictly yeast slurry that settles at the bottom? Getting 2.75L of settlement sounds absolutely ridiculous but then again pitching a gallon starter for imperial stouts isn't unrealistic.

I'm pitching two 2L simply because I don't know how healthy that champagne yeast is... and I've got two stir plates, so why not?

EDIT: A better way of asking is: does Mr. Malty calculator assume you're cold crashing and decanting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the tab that says "repitching from slurry" and it will show the volume of (packed) yeast that calculated. It will be much less than the volume shown on the first tab, which seems to be the 2.75L you referred to above.